# How do I get real-time information from an API with Nuxt framework what refreshes automatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, socket.io, nuxt.js

I've been using nuxt for a while now and I'm wondering how can I get information from some JSON api which updates automatically on the website?

I had read something with SocketIO and Axios.
Does anyone have any advice on how best to do that?

I tried something with Axios. It just doesn't work automatically

Comment: Does the API support WebHooks or some other push-style mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

There are few approaches:

- [Long polling](https://javascript.info/long-polling) (or any kind of "let me send an axios call every `x` seconds): quite naive but can do the job in some situations, not the best in the long term
- [Server Sent Events](https://javascript.info/server-sent-events): unidirectional with some limitations, can be enough depending on your use-case
- [Websockets](https://javascript.info/websocket), bi-directionnal and by far the most efficient way of having communication in real time in both directions.

[SocketIO](https://socket.io/) is indeed the most common approach if you have a JS backend + frontend. Otherwise, your backend may have it's own solution already baked-in, like [Action Cable](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) for Ruby on Rails.

---

For Nuxt (2 and 3), you can use [this module](https://github.com/richardeschloss/nuxt-socket-io). It's not officially maintained by the core team but it may be enough if you don't want to write that part yourself.

PS: some questions regarding Nuxt + socket.io have already been asked here, you could give it a search if you're interested.